# How add node before doubly linked list c++

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I am making a code for double linked list in C++. But, i have a problem, I dont know how add node before other node.
I have these.

```
template<class T>
void LinkedListD<T>::addNodeBeforeTo(Node<T> *before, T info) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>( info );
    if ( isEmpty() ){
        head = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    } else{
        if ( before == head ){
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;

        } if ( before == last ){
            newNode->previous = last;
            last = newNode;
        }
        else{
            Node<T>* act = head;
            Node<T>* past = last;
            while ( act->next != before && past->previous != before){
                act = act->next;
                past = past->previous;
            }
            newNode->previous = past->previous;
            newNode->next = act->next;
            act->next = newNode;
            past->previous = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

The example is 10, 15, 20, 12
Add node before to 20: 30
Finish Output 10, 15, 30, 20, 12
Thks

Comment: You have a while loop that seems to be searching for the before node... why are you doing that? You already have a pointer to the before node and because this is a doubly linked list the before node knows the previous and next node. That is all the information you need. There should be no loops in the code. Because this seems like a homework problem I'm not going to post code directly.

Comment: Sorry if I used while, but I was relying on a simple linked list. With the double list there is no need to traverse the nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `while` loop at all.  Each node knows the nodes on both sides of it, that is all you need to update the list properly.  Given the input node `before`, all you have to do is:

- set `newNode->previous` to point at the `before->previous` node
- set `newNode->next` to point at the `before` node
- if `before->previous` is not null, set `before->previous->next` to point at the `newNode` node
- set `before->previous` to point at the `newNode` node
- if `before` is pointing at the `head` node, set `head` to point at the `newNode` node.

Done.

Also, you have some other logic errors in this code. When inserting *before* the `head` node, you are not updating `head->previous` to point at the `newNode` node before updating `head` itself.  And since your function inserts *before* a given node, you should not be trying to insert *after* the `last` node at all, that job should be handled by a separate `addNodeAfterTo()` method instead.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
Node<T>* LinkedListD<T>::addNodeBeforeTo(Node<T> *before, const T &info) {
    if ( !before ) return nullptr;
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>( info );
    newNode->previous = before->previous;
    newNode->next = before;
    if ( before->previous )
        before->previous->next = newNode;
    before->previous = newNode;
    if ( before == head )
        head = newNode;
    return newNode;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/0RkYlq)

Comment: I have tried it. I have another method to add later, the problem was when it showed the nodes, because I have another bool method to show from back to front and vice versa. I have changed it as if it shows a normal list and it has worked

Comment: For the problem with the head: The solution is in the if ( before == head ) newNode->next = head
        head = newNode;

Answer (score 2):

You have to realize how to approach the solution, **methodically** (n is the object you want to insert the new_item object before it):

```
if (head != nullptr) // i.e. if list is not empty
{
```

[image]

```
}

if (new_item.P == nullptr) // i.e. if new_item is first
     head = new_item;
```

Comment: Ok. So isn't it necessary to have the last item?

Comment: @Fandi , "necessary" it is not. It is optional to have it Like if you want to add items *after* the last item, or to reverse-iterate from last to first *more efficiently* i.e without reaching the last object via the first one. But in any case this issue is not related to your question at the title.